# Error 48 loading dll after rebuilding code, MSADO-related

Tags: dll, vb6, activex, ado

I am getting confusing and seemingly inconsistent results with one ActiveX DLL trying to create an instance of another.

Everything worked until we rebuilt our entire codebase, something which had never done since taking it over a few years ago.  We previously just built pieces as we needed them.

The problem is occurring in multiple places, but here is a representative example:

```
Dim objMid As MiddlePiece.clsMyClass
Set objMid = CreateObject("MiddlePiece.clsMyClass")
```

This is hitting an error (48: Error in loading DLL) on the `CreateObject` line.  I tried changing around the code and came up with the following results.

```
Dim objMid As MiddlePiece.clsMyClass
Set objMid = New MiddlePiece.clsMyClass
```

That gives me error 48 again.

```
Dim objMid As Object
Set objMid = New MiddlePiece.clsMyClass
```

That also gives error 48.

```
Dim objMid As Object
Set objMid = CreateObject("MiddlePiece.clsMyClass")
```

That one actually works.

Can anyone explain what the real difference is between these, and why only the last one works now, whereas at least the first one was working before?

I think I understand the difference between early and late binding, and that only the last example is an instance of late binding, but I've checked and confirmed that on both the build PC and the test machine, the registry contains the same version of MiddlePiece.dll, so I'm not clear on why this would fail.

The problem seems to stem from the fact that MiddlePiece.dll was built with Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects.  There have been numerous issues related to this ever since we moved from Windows XP to Windows 7.  The msado26.tlb library no longer worked for us, so we had to change our references to that library to refer to msado60_Backcompat.tlb instead.  That seemed to work for a while, but we've since had more trouble with two different versions of msado15.dll.  The newest version is breaking code in both VB6 and C++.

Comment: Did you delete the old DLLs? If you delete the DLLs and then compile it makes up a new GUID. If the DLL already exists the guid gets read from the existing file. The last example you gave looks up the GUID in the registry and so works

Comment: We use binary compatibility to maintain IDs.  We have tracked down this problem.  I'll add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We replaced all references to msado60_backcompat.tlb with references to msado26.tlb, essentially undoing a "fix" we first implemented when we transitioned to Windows 7 about two years ago.  This is basically all due to problems introduced by Microsoft.  A good starting place to research the issue, for those who care to know is [here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640696) This allowed us to rebuild everything on the Windows 7 machine and resolve multiple issues.